# Installation error in Service mesh Linkerd in aks

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, linkerd

I have followed the getting started instructions here: **https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/** for installing linkerd but i am not able to install cli of linkerd.

Please see the command below: **curl -sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh**

Please see the error below:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'https://run.linkerd.io/install'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl --sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you.  The way I resolved it is as follows:

1) Install WSL for Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10.
2) Install Ubuntu from the Windows store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

Then launch the Ubuntu shell and follow the instructions again.  Please note this is not a virtual machine - just a shell.

Comment: You don't need to do it, You can simply [download](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/releases/download/edge-20.5.2/linkerd2-cli-edge-20.5.2-windows.exe) the windows binary, rename it and use as you do on linux.

Comment: @mWatney, the command window just flashes when I tried to run this.  Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: You have to execute it in the command line. PowerShell or CMD. This is the executable, not an installer.

Comment: if you run it by simply double clicking it then a command window appears and says please run inside a command window.